# Storing specific columns from second tab of excel sheet in an array list in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to store specific columns from the second tab of excel sheet in an array list. It is storing from the first tab. Please help

Comment: Hi Giridhar, can you add your code please? It makes finding answers much easier.

Comment: I think you are probably referring to sheet, I mean there are multiple sheet in that excel file. Read the sheet with index using Apache POI

Comment: Or use `wb.getSheet("sheetName");` in case you move the sheets around. This way you always read from the same sheet, no matter the order

Answer (score 0):

I have read excel file by using the following code, try this It may help you.

```
String excelFilePath = "";//excel file path 

// GET WORKBOOK
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

Workbook readWorkbook = null;

if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xlsx")) {
    readWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    } else if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xls") || excelFilePath.endsWith("xlsm")) {
    readWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
}

int numberOfSheets = readWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();

DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {

    Sheet sheet = readWorkbook.getSheetAt(i);

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();


    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Cell cell = row.getCell(2);//column Index

        String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);//This is your final answer

    } // while


}//numberOfSheets
```

Comment: Hi @objectif Thanks for your help... What if I want to store Column 1 data in one array list and column 3 data in another list?

Comment: You should declare arraylist before the while loop, and add data wherever you want to store in it.